# Changing classes in a menu with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to create a very simple functionality of clicking on a menu tab and it changes color to let you know what page you are on.  I am a novice so please take it easy on me...lol

/*Menu in php header file*/

```
<ul class="tabs" id="tabs">
  <li class="selected"><a href="http://bestofthebestent.com/index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li class="inactive"><a href="http://bestofthebestent.com/bio.php">Bio</a></li>
  <li class="inactive"><a href="http://bestofthebestent.com/photo.php">Photo</a></li>
  <li class="inactive"><a href="http://bestofthebestent.com/music.php">Thank</a></li>
  <li class="inactive"><a href="http://bestofthebestent.com/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

/*This is the JavaScript file*/
window.onload = initPage;

function initPage() {
    var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
        var links = tabs[i];
        links.onclick = tabClicked;
    }
}


function tabClicked(){
    var tabId = this.id;
    document.getElementById(tabId).classList.toggle("selected");
    var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i < tabs.length; i++){
        var currentTab = tabs[i];
        if (currentTab.id !== tabId){
            currentTab.class = "selected";
        } else {
            currentTab.class = "inactive";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here? one thing for sure is you are looking for `var tabId = this.id;` when there is no id for any of the lis.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store a reference to each of the list items.
2. Create a variable to keep track of the current tab.
3. In an onclick function for each element (or you could use one onclick and just use some conditions), change the class attribute of the element by using the `setAttribute()` method.

Like this:

```
function onFirstTabClick() {
    clearSelected();
    tabVariable1.setAttribute("class","some-new-class");
}

function() clearSelected() {
    switch(currentSelectedTrackerVariable) {
case 1: tabVariable1.setAttribute("class","some-new-class");
break;
// Do this for the amount of tabs that you have.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element.setAttribute("class", "className");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ids` in your code but you don't have provided it in your markup. so give ids to `li` elements and try this.

```
function tabClicked(){
    var tabId = this.id;
    document.getElementById(tabId).classList.toggle("selected");
    var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i < tabs.length; i++){
        var currentTab = tabs[i];
        if (currentTab.id !== tabId){
            currentTab.className = "inactive";
        } else {
            currentTab.className= "selected";
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PLXpc/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/wRVr6/)**</kbd>

There is no need to define functions globally. Write all them in one package. The code below, works correctly with **your HTML markup**.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var tab = document.getElementById('tabs');
    var lis = tab.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
        lis[i].onclick = function () {
            for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                lis[j]["className"] = "inactive";
            }

            this["className"] = "selected";
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery, then `tabClicked` can run:

```
   jQuery('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('inactive');
   jQuery(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: True, he isn't in his code above, but he said he was a novice (and clearly a beginner from looking at his code). And since he didn't say standard javascript only, I mentioned that "if you use jQuery" the code can be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: I understand, but he said what he was using. It's best to answer his question within the parameters it was asked. Giving him a solution using a library he's not implementing isn't helpful to him. Giving him jQuery as an addendum is fine, just not as the primary answer.

Comment: I agree, hence why I upvoted the incomplete solution above which gave him the necessary tools to figure it out on his own (yours).